# Gradle-Wrapper.Properties does not exist (Cordova)

Tags: java, android, cordova, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've been having the same problem for two days now, and I can't seem to get Cordova to do what I want.

Background:

~ I have every Android SDK installed on my machine

~ My `PATH` includes SDK tools and platform-tools, under the filepath the exist on my computer

~ I created an environment variable for `ANDROID_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME`, as described on the Cordova page.

~ I am only trying to run the program in Android, Cordova says that I meet all requirements when I call Cordova requirements

~ I have done `Cordova platform rm android --save / add`, multiple times

~ I am running Cordova 6.2.1 and Android@5.0.0 (wouldn't install Android@5.2.1 for some reason)

I am new to Cordova, so maybe I missed some essential, and basic test, but I am getting a confusing error.

Error: (occurs when I try `Cordova build|run|clean --verbose`)

```
ANDROID_HOME=myPathToMyAndroid\sdk
JAVA_HOME=myPathToMYJava\jdk1.8.0_91
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Wrapper properties file '\Users\myName\!Projects\myApplication\platforms\android\gradle\wrapper\gradle-wrapper.properties' does not exist.
at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.forWrapperPropertiesFile(WrapperExecutor.java:47)
at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:47)
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
at /callbackString/
```

This baffles me mostly because everything in the gradle file is constantly being rebuilt, including everything in the gradle\wrapper file.

I am working on a networked drive at work and have a proxy, but I don't really know if that matters, but I don't really know what information is relevant with this issue, because I can't find a single other case of this happening on the internet.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT:

Worth noting, I HAVE a gradle-wrapper.properties file in my file system, but on the Windows file system it only reads as gradle-wrapper without the extension. I'm running Windows 7 Enterprise.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but try a 1.6 or 1.7 Java install

Comment: Just did an install of Java 1.7.0_79, same exact error still (except jdk1.7.0_79 obviously)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, I figured out the issue, and it seems to be a rather personal issue, and most likely will not be an issue for many other people. But, in case it is an issue for someone in the future I will answer it.

As I said, at my work we have networked drives, I had my project folder on a networked drive instead of my C: drive. Once I moved the project folder to the C drive it worked as it should.

Comment: please mark your answer as the solving one, thanks! :)

Comment: I'll be able to in 5 hours

Comment: I have the same problem, but no network drive. I am using a file system on the "d" drive. I don't know if that matters.

Comment: Basically, it just has to be on the same network that you have Cordova/npm installed on. When you do the command `npm install Cordova -g` it will install it to your computer's hard drive the 'C:' drive on Windows. If your project is not on your main drive, I suggest you try and move it to your main drive and see if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/66121086/9138027 ... If you don't find it create it yourself and sync the project.

Answer (score 0):

I think it tries to use the Gradle Wrapper but it's missing the gradle-wrapper.properties file which includes relevant version information. So I suggest to add the wrapper to your project and re-run the task. More details about the wrapper: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Comment: Yeah, I thought of that. The problem is that the gradle wrapper and all files inside, including the gradle-wrapper.properties file, get rewritten every time Cordova builds the project. So, even if I put in a properties file (which I have done), it just overwrites the file and says it's gone again. Is there a way to force it to create a wrapper.properties file in the config or something?

Comment: Worth noting, I do HAVE a gradle-wrapper.properties file in my file system.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue, after multiple re-installs of the platform and setting all the env vars it worked. First I executed

```
cordova clean android
```

it was successful, next

```
ionic cordova build android
```

I am not sure, but it seems that running 'clean' first cleared the build env for subsequent successful 'build'
Hope it helps.