# \gradle-wrapper.properties not found in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build

**\gradle-wrapper.properties not found in Android Studio**

I have cloned a git project and I am getting the below issue.

[image]

**How to resolve it?**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` file and also put the `gradle-wrapper.jar` file in the same directory.

That's how the `gradle-wrapper.properties` file should look like:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-bin.zip
```

You can also just copy the `gradle` directory from another project and edit the wrapper version.

Answer (score 3):

If it could be usefull, i will suggest the Official Doc:
[adding_wrapper](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html#sec:adding_wrapper)

> Running the Wrapper task
>
> ```
> $ gradle wrapper
> > Task :wrapper
>
> BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
> 1 actionable task: 1 executed
> ```

Then The generated Wrapper properties file, `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties`, stores the information about the Gradle distribution.

Comment: That would be a lot easier if I could find the `gradle` command. I'm running Ubuntu and very leery of actually installing gradle as a system package, as it is clearly present in Android Studio and should be kept updated better, there.

Answer (score 0):

first you most create `{app name}\gradle\wrapper` folder and also create file `gradle-wrapper.properties`.

add this line to `gradle-wrapper.properties`:

```html
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.2-bin.zip
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
```

also you can that folder (`{app name}\gradle\wrapper`) from another project.